# Primary key dialog in pgamin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am working on pgadmin 4 tool to structure my table.

I was wondering where is the primary key dialog as mentioned in the help documentation?

I have created a table and columns. But how do i get to the primary key dialog ?

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/primary_key_dialog.html

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

Primary Key is a constraint.

So it can be created by right clicking on the constraints node and click on new constraint.

Not very intuitive help documentation i have to say.

Best Regards,

Saurav